# Trouble accessing nested model's attributes in home controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model `Form` which has an has_many relationship to a model `User`.  `User` belongs_to `Form`.

I'm trying to access the values in `User` from my `HomeController`:

```
  @forms = Form.all 
  @forms_by_val = @forms.users.group_by(&:value)
```

But this is giving me the error.  Any ideas how to fix?:

> undefined method `users' for # Array:0x007fdb32672dd8>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@forms` that is `Form.all` refer to the array that have Form instances. `users` method is only available to a Form instance. Not to an array of Form instances.

I think you are trying to do something like this.

`@forms_by_val = @forms.map {|form| form.users }.flatten`

This will give you an array of users that belong to individual forms.

If you want a unique list of users...

`@forms_by_val = @forms.map {|form| form.users }.flatten.uniq`